# Hive padding leading zeroes

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata

I need the output of a string column in my table as 13 length char, irrespective of whatever length it is, i need to stuff the remaining chars with 0...

I tried to use the following code in my hive query, but failed to get the desired output

```
right('0000000000000' + ProductID, 13)
```

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Hive has built-in lpad and rpad functions. In your case you could use:

```
lpad(ProductId, 13, "0")
```

Or, if you might need to truncate to 13 characters, you could wrap this in the "right" function.

Comment: just what I needed! Thnx!

Comment: Awesome  it really helps.

Comment: ('41405'||lpad(hex_to_int(ci),10,'0'))  - please help me

Comment: just be mindful that if you have negative numbers this will add the leading zeros before the negative sign. for example 0000-123. It will not do -0000123